# I don't think what it wants is true, $\iint_{B_r}f(x,y)dxdy=0$ for all $r$ means $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been asked to show that if (where $B_r(a)=B_r=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<r^2\}$ - ie open ball at a) to prove (that if f is continuous):

$$\iint_{B_r}f(x,y)dxdy=0$$ for all $r$

that $f(x,y)=0$ always.

Okay if $f(x,y)=0$ then the result follows trivially, so the iff thing doesn't matter.

But I don't agree with the next part.

$\iint_{B_{r_1}-B_{r_2}}f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{B_{r_1}}f(x,y)dxdy-\iint_{B_{r_2}}f(x,y)dxdy$ where $0<r_1<r_2$

By the continuity of $f$ the integrals are continuous (bounded interval, result is bounded and cont)

Now think about it, all we know is that over a disk shape that the integral is 0, now we know that over a washer shape it is 0, all well and good.

Now imagine a function that goes up and down radially, like a cupcake wrapper sort of shape, crinckled. If there's the same number of "ups" as "downs" the integral around will be zero, but the cup cake wrapper is not flat!

So have I missed something or is the question wrong?

Comment: isn't it for all $a$ also ? Because if $a=0$ is fixed, I think you're right

Comment: Are you sure the balls to be considered are all centered at $0$?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui that's a really good point, if a isn't fixed how would the proof go? (I stumbled on this contradiction trying to find a way)

Comment: If the balls _are_ all $0$-centered, then a simple counterexample would be $f(x,y)=x$.

Comment: The balls are not all centred, not sure what to do now.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was just about to put $f(x,y)=y$!

Comment: @HenningMakholm should I pose a new question or edit this? I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof (it's easy in one dimension because there are 2 directions, the intersection of intervals is an interval! Not sure what to do here, balls are pretty easy but with no mark scheme I couldn't be sure I was right.

Comment: Are you sure it is "$f(x,y)=0$ always" and not "$f(x,y)$ almost everywhere"?

Comment: @Mark: That was actually the one was imagining in my mind. But my inner make-the-math-simpler circuit overrode that and said that if I'm mentioning only one variable, let it be the first one! :-)

Comment: @Git: $f$ is assumed continuous, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was never going to define my cup-cake thing... just want to put that out there! I got scared my thinking about how to prove it leading to something which contradicted. Of course the person with $f(x,y)=x$ wins, we must fall back on alphabetical order, as x<y even if you used f(a,b)=a it holds still - I'll get my coat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the balls are not centered (see comments), then :

if $f$ is not null, there exists $a$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$. Without lost of generality, we will assume $f(a) > 0$. By continuity, you can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall x \in B_a(\epsilon), f(x) > 0$. Then $\int_{B_a{\epsilon}} f > 0$. So if the integral is null for all ($a,\epsilon$) then $f$ must be null.

If the ball must be centered on a fixed $a$, then you're right, the statement is false.

Comment: Of course! The non vanishing lemma! I even used balls to prove that (they just were not very round :P) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think there must be a lost assumption that your integral is to be $0$ for any ball centered anywhere, not just for ones centered at $0$.

With the assumption you have, you can at least prove that $f(0)=0$. Namely, if $f(0)=c>0$, then because $f$ is continuous there's a ball $B_r(0)$ inside which $f$ is always at least $c/2$. And then the integral over that ball is clearly $\ge\frac{cr^2\pi}{2}$.

If *all* balls are considered, this argument can be repeated for other centers.